# Calculate Average of N integers in C using only integer arithmetic and without keeping N values

Tags: c

I have an embedded C program in a constrained system which reads sensor measurements. I would like to calculate a running average during the last N sensor readings from the time that some event takes place. I want the calculation to use only integer operations (no floating point). Also I don't have enough storage to maintain all N readings so I want to create a running average total somehow and add to that total each time I get a new reading. One formula that I have seen to approximate this is

```
avg = ((avg * (n-1)) + currentReading) / n;
```

When I coded and tested this, however the calculated average was always less than if I add all the N readings and divided by N. How to improve this?

Comment: Where's your question ?

Comment: And what problems do you have with your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get exactly what you want unless you keep the last N samples, but you can approximate it with:

```
avg = ((avg * (n-1)) + currentReading + (n/2)) / n;
```

This weights the current reading to have 1/n significance in the average.

Comment: This solution uses 1 integer division per value. The integer division is a truncating operation so that over many values the average will be lower that the exact calculation. I think that if you modify the division to be a rounding integer division, the answer will be closer to the real average over lots of values.

Comment: You can add N/2 before dividing.

Answer (score 2):

Just keep the running total along the number of values - two integers required. Simple sum at the end (or whenever you want).

Comment: This does not compute the running average of the last `N` sample readings.

Answer (score 0):

OP's code is close yet would benefit with a *rounded division* rather than standard *integer division*.  So add a bias.  The bias depends on the sign of the operands.

```
// avg = ((avg * (n-1)) + currentReading) / n;
avg = (avg * (n-1)) + currentReading + bias) / n;
```

A 2nd problem is one of range: `(avg * (n-1)) + currentReading` easily overflow.  The simplest solution to resort to wider math.  Use a wider type

```
// Example, depends on system
// avg * (n-1)) + currentReading
1uLL * avg * (n-1)) + currentReading
```

Putting this together:

```
// avg = ((avg * (n-1)) + currentReading) / n;
int avg, currentReading;
int n; // n > 0
int2x numerator;  // int2x some type 2x wide as int, maybe long long

numerator = (int2x)avg * (n-1) + currentReading;  // Wider math
int bias = n/2;
if (numerator < 0) bias = -bias;
numerator += bias;

avg = (int) (numerator / n);
```